# Use (DI injected) DbContext after request ended in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For my ASP.NET Core MVC application I need a controller action which processes data. This processing takes some time so I do not want to block the request. In the controller action I rather start a background worker and end the request immediately telling the user that the processing is in progress. A second controller action is then used to access the processed data.

In the background worker I need to access the `DbContext` for storing the processed data in my database. (Or any other service which was injected via Dependency Injection.) I found that creating a new, request-independent scope via an `IServiceScopeFactory` works which in turn gives me a `ServiceProvider`:

```
public class ProcessingController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory mServiceProvider;

    public HomeController(IServiceScopeFactory serviceProvider)
    {
        mServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public IActionResult BeginProcessing(int id)
    {
        var longRunningScope = mServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        var _ = Task.Run(() => {
            try {
                var context = longRunningScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
                var workItem = context.Items.First(i => i.Id == id) 
                ...
            }
            finally {
                longRunningScope.Dispose();
            }
        });
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Is there a better (more ASP.NET-Core-style) way to do this? Please note that my "long-running" action only takes 2-5 seconds and that multiple users need to be handled simultaneously. A background thread which processes requests in sequence is not wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that a [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) is not well suited for my needs because it needs to be implemented explicitly and injected, making it hard to pass data to it.

Here is a more flexible and easier to use solution `ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner`, which runs an action in its own task and in its own scope while listening to the shutdown event. The action receives the corresponding cancellation token as well as a scoped `ServiceProvider` to obtain any needed services.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication2.Support
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Service class that executes tasks which run in their own thread with their own scope
    /// and can thus continue executing after the web request ended.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Register via:
    /// services.AddTransient<ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner>();
    /// </remarks>
    public class ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner> mLogger;
        private CancellationTokenSource mStoppingCts;
        private IServiceProvider mServiceProvider;

        public ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner(IServiceProvider services,
            ILogger<ScopedBackgroundTaskRunner> logger,
            IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            mServiceProvider = services;
            mLogger = logger;
            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnAppStopping);
        }

        private void OnAppStopping()
        {
            if (mStoppingCts != null)
            {
                mLogger.LogDebug($"Cancel due to app shutdown");
                mStoppingCts.Cancel();
            }
        }

        public void Execute(Action<IServiceProvider, CancellationToken> action, CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
            Execute(action, "<unnamed>", stoppingToken);
        }
        public void Execute(Action<IServiceProvider, CancellationToken> action, string actionName, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            mStoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
            var scope = mServiceProvider.CreateScope();
            var _ = Task.Run(() => {
                mLogger.LogTrace($"Executing action '{actionName}' on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}...");
                try
                {
                    action.Invoke(scope.ServiceProvider, mStoppingCts.Token);
                }
                finally {
                    mLogger.LogTrace($"Action '{actionName}' {(mStoppingCts.IsCancellationRequested ? "canceled" : "finished")}" +
                        $" on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    scope.Dispose();
                    var mStoppingCtsCopy = mStoppingCts;
                    mStoppingCts = null;
                    mStoppingCtsCopy.Dispose();
                }
            }, mStoppingCts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing your background task as a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

With that approach, the lifetime of your background service is managed (the runtime will request cancellation via a `CancellationToken` if the hosting environment is shutting down, whereas, in your existing code, your task would not be politely stopped).

Comment: I read about ``IHostedService`` but the problem I have with this DI approach is: How can I pass data from the controller action to the worker? I added parameter `id` which my `Task` is using to find the needed `workItem`.

Valid point about the `CancellationToken`, I guess I would have to use `IApplicationLifetime` to support a proper runtime shutdown.

Comment: You can dependency inject your background service into your controller like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105917/how-to-pass-data-from-a-controller-to-a-background-service