# How to start my Background service by button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, backgroundworker

I have a requirement: if I click button the background service will start what I have to do for this .Basically it is an ASP.NET MVC project

```
public class TimeHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<TimeHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    private readonly IEmailService worker;

    public TimeHostedService(ILogger<TimeHostedService> logger, IEmailService worker)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    //public async Task StartAsync(int id)
    //{
    //    while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    //    {
    //        _logger.LogInformation("Timed background service is started");
    //        await this.worker.SendEmailCampaignStatusAsync(id);
    //        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cancellationToken);
    //    }
    //}

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
  
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed background service is started");
            await this.worker.SendMailCampainStatusAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented like this but I am not getting any way to background service start by button click and there is no involvement of controller also. directly it will trigger background service. What do I have to do for this?

```
<form >
    <button type="submit" id="sendEmailButton">Send EMail</button>
</form>
<script>

$("#sendEmailButton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:5001/api/TimeHostedService/StartAsync",
       
        },   
});
</script>
```

This is for button I don't have idea about this.

Comment: You need to implement code in your controller . Here is a similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105917/how-to-pass-data-from-a-controller-to-a-background-service

Comment: there is no involvement of controller @firatt_

Comment: there is no loading also